# Vue.js – why is my debounce function not working with arrow function

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Here is my debounce function:

```
function debounce(fn, wait = 1500) {
  let timeout;
  return function (...args) {
    if (timeout) clearTimeout(timeout);
    let context = this;
    timeout = setTimeout(function () {
      fn.apply(context, ...args);
    }, wait);
  };
}
```

Here is my `method` in the component:

```
methods: {
    onKeyUp() {
      if(this.q.length) this.isLoading = true; // show loading spinner
      return debounce(() => this.querySearch())()
    },
```

So I have to execute the debounce call with an extra set of `()` which makes sense, because debounce returns a function. Now, if I change it to this:

```
methods: {
    onKeyUp: debounce(function() { 
       this.querySearch()
    })
```

I don't understand why this works – `debounce` returns a function. I would expect when `onKeyUp` is triggered, it would run `debounce` - which just returns a function, without ever executing it. Does it implicitly execute the returned function with this syntax? Why?

Also, why does it need to be a non-arrow function in the second example? I know in the first example you want an arrow fn because you want `this` to point to the component context, but im unclear why using this key-value syntax breaks that down here.

Comment: Note that `onKeyup: debounce()` as you've done in the second example can be [problematic if you have multiple instances of the component](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html#stateful-methods).

Comment: [call, apply and bind do not work with arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#call_apply_and_bind)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`debounce(function() {...})` is an expression. `onKeyUp` is assigned to the result of its evaluation. The result of `debounce` call is debounced function, so is `onKeyUp`.

> I would expect when onKeyUp is triggered, it would run debounce

This isn't how JavaScript works. Given `var foo = 1 + 1`, `1 + 1` is eagerly evaluated to 2, not at the time when `foo` variable is accessed. The only possibility for the code to be lazily evaluated is to wrap it inside a function. This is what happens in case of `debounce`. The code inside `function() {...}` is called after a delay when debounced function is called. `debounce` itself is called when it's called.

> Also, why does it need to be a non-arrow function in the second example

Because this is the only way the function can get component instance as `this`. Since arrows don't have their own context, `this` would refer to outer context with an arrow, which is module context in which the component is defined:

```
onKeyUp: debounce(() => {...})
```

and

```
onKeyUp: () => {...}
```